monitor the price of coins
I have a virtual pool with token pairs sol/memecoin. i want to draw a k-line chart (pump.fun one) to reflect the coin price. How should I do it? Should I listen to my pool account's token balance and write it to the database or should I listen to my contract's methods (buy, sell, which writes an event to record the number of tokens in the previous pair and the number of tokens in the subsequent pair) and write it to the database and return it to the k-chart plugin in the specified format. Also need to listen to the market capitalisation, if the market capitalisation reaches a criterion, it will be listed.
